# Red5 changing the default location of storing media files

Tags: red5

I've just started playing with Red5 and am developing an app using which users can record video messages. 
Now by default the video files are being saved in

C:\Program Files\Red5\webapps\webcam_recorder\streams

I am trying to figure out how I can change the default location and say be able to save it in c:\streams instead

Secondly once I deploy to prod, my idea is to save these video files on Amazon S3 and have red5 stream from there. Is that possible. If so where in the config will I specify this change.

Thanks a lot for your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to follow the instructions on this links and change the default location
Hope it helps others:

http://www.red5tutorials.net/index.php/Tutorials:Streaming_from_custom_directories

Comment: any chance you can repost the tutorial? Dead link.